# problems with clamav-daemon.socket

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, dpkg, clamav

I'm trying to update my `clamav`, but I've tried everything I know and nothing has helped. I keep getting these kinds of error messages. Any help is very much appreciated.

I've also tried everything I could find on the net (remove, purge, reinstall) to no avail. Please help... :( It's stopping me from installing other programs too.

Terminal:

```
root@dell-Latitude-D630:/home/dell# apt-get -f install clamav-daemon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  clamav-docs daemon
Recommended packages:
  clamdscan
The following packages will be upgraded:
  clamav-daemon
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/200 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 675823 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../clamav-daemon_0.99.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_i386.deb ...
Failed to stop clamav-daemon.socket: Unit clamav-daemon.socket not loaded.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to stop clamav-daemon.socket: Unit clamav-daemon.socket not loaded.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/clamav-daemon_0.99.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
insserv: warning: script 'K01maldet' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'maldet' missing LSB tags and overrides
Failed to start clamav-daemon.service: Unit clamav-daemon.socket is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status clamav-daemon.service' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript clamav-daemon, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/clamav-daemon_0.99.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@dell-Latitude-D630:/home/dell#
```

---

```
root@dell-Latitude-D630:/home/dell# sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq clamav-daemon
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
(Reading database ... 675758 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing clamav-daemon (0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Failed to stop clamav-daemon.socket: Unit clamav-daemon.socket not loaded.
dpkg: error processing package clamav-daemon (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 clamav-daemon
root@dell-Latitude-D630:/home/dell#
```

Comment: Thank you for making my question more presentable Zanna :)

Comment: File a bug report and try this - http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Comment: bodhi.zazen, I tried but I got the error in the OP. Tried to add here but said it was too long.

Comment: keep going there are a number of commands to run next. `dpkg --remove --force-all clamav-daemon` and then if necessary, `cd /var/lib/dpkg/info` and start removing, keep going .....

Comment: Thanks bodhi.zazen, I'm not very fluent with this stuff, appreciate your patience :)

Comment: It is alright, not many people have much experience with apt fails. Just keep going and post any errors you get and ask if you get stuck.

Comment: bodhi.zazen, you're a life saver! I just did cd /var/lib/dpkg/info  , then did rm clamav* , then did apt purge clamav* , that seemed to remove everything, then just did apt-get install clamav and all is good! Thank you SO much!

Comment: I posted the above for any future readers. I was worried about deleting anything from dpkg, wasn't sure if I'd kill my system :) I'm very happy you were here. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to bodhi.zazen's help I was able to finally fix this issue.

What worked:

```
su
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
rm clamav*
apt purge clamav*
apt-get install clamav
```

This fixed my problem and now clamav is working again and I'm now able to install other programs.

Answer (score 0):

I am a low level user of Linux, so when I carried out a recent update to Ubuntu Server 17.04, I believe it was Clamav and a couple of other libraries that were applied. If I am not mistaken Clamav updated to 0.9.3, but I could be wrong.

Anyway I encounted the Unix Socket missing error in postfix and checked, and yes /run/clamav/clamd.ctl was not their, rebooted but still the same and clamav was unable to function on Mail Server without warnings and attempts to find backup alternatives.

I spent a full 2 days researching and applying ALL of the remedies listed by the various groups but could not rectify the problem no matter what I tried. Even those that provided fixes that supposedly worked fail dismally.

I have a seporate BACKUP drive that includes CloneZilla images and also a folder that carries a CPIO file backup using the following command.

Server1# find . -mount -print | cpio -pdumv /BACKUP/TLCSMail_Backup_17.04LTS

and I keep this updated regularly as changes/updates are applied. Now I was prepared  to re-instate the CloneZilla Image as it was only about a month ago I upgraded from 16.10LTS to 17.04LTS, but rather than be that drastic I had nothing to loose by simply mounting the /BACKUP drive and using the following command RESTORE /etc and reboot and see what happens.

cd /BACKUP/TLCSMail_Backup_17.04LTS

cd etc

find . -mount -print | cpio -pdumv /etc

To my surprise it did not effect the system even though it was live, I re-booted and all was back to normal operation. I carried out an apt update, then apt upgrade and there was NO changes or additions required.

Clamav was again version 0.9.2 and postfix was a s happy as a lark. It has now been running for 2.5 days without any issue.

Wish I had tried it earlier and saved a lot of PAIN, but I wanted to learn....... Hope this is of help to other encountering this problem, I really do not approve of the Disable Clamav as some posts indicate to fix the issue, for too long Linux and Apple systems have blatantly transmitted virus to the deterent of Windows users and systems.

Very best regards
Terry Lamb.